# PyQt5 crashed python when i add widget to a second window

Tags: python, pyqt5

when i attempt to add a widget to the second window it crashes

```
    Class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            self.setWindowTitle("Window 1")

            self.Button = Qt.QPushButton("to second")
            self.Button.clicked.connect(self.opensecond)
        def opensecond(self):
            self.close()
            self.secondpage = Second()

   Class Second(Qt.QMainWindow):
       def __init__():
           self.setWindowTitle("Window 2")
           self.Layout = Qt.QGridLayout()
           self.setLayout = Qt.QGridLayout()

           #self.IsLabel = Qt.QLabel("This should show")
```

The Above Code works fine 
However when i uncomment self.IsLabel, this Window Crashed the full application. Apple Problem report is below (i have the full document if required)

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

(i have only shared the code i felt was relevant if you feel there is something missing i can provide more)

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Even when sharing only part of your code, ensure that its sintax is correct (`class` should be lowercase) and that you provide all relevant part. For example, you're using an uncommon (and, I'd say, a bit unorthodox) way of importing Qt classes and modules, which is probably the reason of your problem: you've probably forgot to import QLabel from QtWidgets, but since we don't exactly know how you did those imports, that's hard to tell. For future reference, try to run your program in a shell, so that it will provide the full python traceback, as macOS reports are completely useless.

Comment: Okay I have had a total n00b moment and i figured out why my app wouldn't launch from shell 
Okay so i am getting no traceback but now it suddenly works (I have honestly just stopped asking why) 
Thanks for answering! 
Cheers again buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one works on Python3 (3.7.5)  Pyqt5 (5.12.3), your code gave a lot of errors on my setup

try it and see what is like on your system

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
            self.setWindowTitle("Window 1")
            Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("To Second") 
            self.setCentralWidget(Button)
            Button.resize(100,100)
            Button.clicked.connect(self.opensecond)
            self.show()

        def opensecond(self):
            self.close()
            self.secondpage = Second()
            self.secondpage.show()

class Second(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
       def __init__(self):
           super(Second, self).__init__()
           self.setWindowTitle("Window 2")
           self.resize(506, 312) 
           IsLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("This should show")
           self.setCentralWidget(IsLabel)
           self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Hello Pippo, 
So i have managed to get this to work with help from yourself and musicamante 
I have voted yours as answer but i have no reputation so it has not counted :( 
I will leave the question up so others can do so

Comment: @StevenJohnson If an answer is what solved your problem, you should mark it as *accepted* (the check mark on the left of the answer, under the voting arrows). Anyway, it's still not very clear exactly *what* your problem was (I'm still pretty sure that it was due to the way you imported Qt modules), and if you can find it out, it would better for everybody to let us know it.

Comment: Hello musicamante 
Thanks i have never asked a question onto here before, and no the import statements still work exactly the same and i have had great success. i think the problem is i was loading it from the IDLE and it only returns tracebacks from the first class i ran, so the second class was just crashing out instead of providing a traceback 
I notice within the shell whenever i get a python quit error it is an issue with either my Controller or my second View Class